# Wildcard Subdomain to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

how can I do that when a user enters to a subdomain (I'll have a wildcard subdomain), he will see what in the subfolder with the same name in the main domain? For example, if user will enter to `works.domain.com`, I want him to see what's in `www.domain.com/works`. Another example: user will enter to `private.domain.com/photos/gallery.php?from=germany&no=3`, he'll see what's in `www.domain.com/private/photos/gallery.php?from=germany&no=3`.

What should I write in the HTACCESS of the wildcard subdomain? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (in document root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %1::%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*?)::/\1/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Add it to the wildcard subdomain?

Comment: Well if you have a wildcard i guess all your subdomains are sharing the same document root folder as `www`. So all you have to do is to create a htaccess file in root folder (if this is not done already) and put the code from my answer into it

Comment: Just to be sure, it doesn't really redirects, I want the user to think that it is a real subdomain, true?

Comment: Yes that's why i used `L` flag (for an internal rewrite) instead of `R` flag (for an external redirect)

Comment: It doesn't work. The original URL: http://www.gincher.net/works/yergraphics/
The URL I'm trying: http://works.gincher.net/yergraphics/

Comment: I've added something to avoid infinite loop error. Could you try again with my edited answer ?

Comment: Still.. Another one for testing: Original: http://www.gincher.net/old, new: http://old.gincher.net/.

Comment: The code i gave you is now working, you just have a 404 not found because `www` and subdomains are not pointing to the same document root

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60345/discussion-between-gincher-and-justin-iurman).

Comment: Just made a test with my code and it's working as expected (with a good configuration of apache server). The problem is on your side (maybe a bad config ? or nginx possibility like i told you)